# Class 'CachedCiviContainer' not found in Civi\Core\Container loadContainer()

Tags: drupal, cache, error-page

I am using CiviCRM 5.9 and Drupal 7.56 hosted in the pantheon server. Yesterday, suddenly my site went down. I have checked with drupal error log, it is showing

php error   : Class 'CachedCiviContainer' not found in Civi\Core\Container->loadContainer() (line 91 of /srv/bindings/242bbe6b8647492ab68ea8088fbf3044/code/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/Core/Con

I thought it is related to caching, so I run clear cache and it worked.

but I couldn't get the exact reason for this issue. Please help.